# Each query takes more time using Structured Streaming with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using Spark 2.3.0, Scala 2.11.8 and Kafka and I'm trying to write into parquet files all the messages from Kafka with Structured Streaming but for each query that my implementation does the total time for each one increase a lot [Spark Stages Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eL4i.png).
I would like to know why this happens, I tried with different possibles triggers (Continues,0 seconds, 1 seconds, 10 seconds,10 minutes, etc) and always I get the same behavior. My code has this structure:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, SparkSession}
import com.name.proto.ProtoMessages
import java.io._
import java.text.{DateFormat, SimpleDateFormat}
import java.util.Date
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.OutputMode

object StructuredStreaming {

  def message_proto(value:Array[Byte]): Map[String, String] = {     

    try {
      val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
      val impression_proto = ProtoMessages.TrackingRequest.parseFrom(value)

      val json = Map(
       "id_req" -> (impression_proto.getIdReq().toString),
       "ts_imp_request" -> (impression_proto.getTsRequest().toString),
       "is_after" -> (impression_proto.getIsAfter().toString),
       "type" -> (impression_proto.getType().toString)
      )    
      return json

    }catch{
      case e:Exception=>
        val pw = new PrintWriter(new File("/home/data/log.log" ))
        pw.write(e.toString)
        pw.close()

        return Map("error" -> "error")       
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]){

    val proto_impressions_udf = udf(message_proto _)
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Structured Streaming ").getOrCreate()
    //fetchOffset.numRetries, fetchOffset.retryIntervalMs
    val stream = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "ip:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "ssp.impressions")
      .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
      .option("max.poll.records", "1000000")
      .option("auto.commit.interval.ms", "100000")
      .option("session.timeout.ms", "10000")
      .option("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
      .option("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer")
      .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
      .option("latestFirst", "true")
      .load()

    try{
      val query = stream.select(col("value").cast("string"))
        .select(proto_impressions_udf(col("value")) as "value_udf")
        .select(col("value_udf")("id_req").as("id_req"), col("value_udf")("is_after").as("is_after"),
          date_format(col("value_udf")("ts_request"), "yyyy").as("date").as("year"),
          date_format(col("value_udf")("ts_request"), "MM").as("date").as("month"),
          date_format(col("value_udf")("ts_request"), "dd").as("date").as("day"),
          date_format(col("value_udf")("ts_request"), "HH").as("date").as("hour"))
      val query2 = query.writeStream.format("parquet")
                        .option("checkpointLocation", "/home/data/impressions/checkpoint")
                        .option("path", "/home/data/impressions")
                        .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
                        .partitionBy("year", "month", "day", "hour")
                        .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("1 seconds"))
                        .start()           
    }catch{    
      case e:Exception=>
        val pw = new PrintWriter(new File("/home/data/log.log" ))
        pw.write(e.toString)
        pw.close()    
    }    
  }
}
```

I attached others images from the Spark UI:

[image: Jobs]
[image: Environment]
[image: Executors]
[image: Thread Dump]
[image: Sql]
[image: Query Plan]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is related to the batches, you need to define a good time for processing each batch, and that depends on your cluster processing power. Also, the time for solve each batch depends whether you are receiving all the fields without null because if you receive a lot of fields on null the process will take less time to process the batch.